# What is a simple AJAX jQuery file uploader?

Tags: ajax, jquery, file-upload

Is there a jQuery AJAX file uploader that makes it simple for me to upload a single file to my server and send data back to the page? I don't want multiple upload, or loading bars etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example site: http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Comment: It relies on jquery 1.2 or if you really want to use this you need to extend jquery by adding your own handleError method since it was deprecated in 1.5.  For handleError see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627201/ajax-upload-plugin-throwing-jquery-handleerror-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example. Everything goes fine except the handler is written in asp.net. Give it a try
http://www.ctoulaparas.com/?p=30