# JqGrid : File Upload not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, file-upload, jqgrid

I am trying to upload file with jqgrid, but the is some mistake in my code.
I am using **onInitializeForm** method.
I am using [Jquery Ajax File Uploader](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)
Can anyone do help to me?
You can see Error in screenshot

[image: Screenshot]
This is my code.

```
    jQuery("#formGrid").jqGrid(
                {
                    url:'application/ajax/common_form_detail.php?form_id='+form_id,
                    editurl:'application/ajax/common_form_edit.php?form_id='+form_id,
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames:[<?php echo $strfield; ?>],
                    colModel:[<?php echo $strFieldModel; ?>],
                        rowNum:20,
                        rowList:[20,50,100],
                        pager: '#formControl',
                        sortname: 'id',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: "asc",
                        autowidth: true,
                        height: 400,
                        width: 900
                });
                jQuery("#formGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#formControl',
                { edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false},
                {width:780,recreateForm:true},
                {width:780,recreateForm:true
                    ,onInitializeForm : function(formid){
                    $(formid).attr('method','POST');
                    $(formid).attr('action','');
                    $(formid).attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
                }, afterSubmit : function(response, postdata){
                       $.ajaxFileUpload({
                          url: 'application/ajax/common_file_upload.php', 
                          secureuri:false,
                          fileElementId:'STUDENT_AVATAR',
                          dataType: 'json',
                          success: function (data, status) {
                              alert("Upload Complete.");
                          }
                       });
                   }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

One can see that you have error in `jQuery.handleError` function which is depreciated from jQuery 1.5. jQuery Ajax File Uploader V2.1 provided from the download page included jQuery 1.2.1.

One have to fix the code of Ajax File Uploader to solve the problem. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13115871/315935) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190291/315935) for example or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7866311/315935). You can consider to use another Plugin for file upload like [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) (and [here](https://github.com/malsup/form/)), see [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

Comment: is there any plugin to upload multiple images ?

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr: Sorry, but I never used file upload plugin in any real projects. Look at http://www.plupload.com/ and https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload. It seems be powerful plugin for files uploading. One should be able to upload multiple files too. It can be used in different ways. I hope it will help you.